# Sentencia SQL SELECT * FROM

Tags: sql-server

**Resumen**

Me gustaría usar una sentencia SQL parecida a la típica que todos usamos

`SELECT * FROM usuario`

Con diferencia que no me gustaria mostar un id en especifico, es decir

muestreme todos los registros pero no me muestre el registro con el id = X

hay forma de lograrlo ?

De todas maneras me date la tarea de investigar <3

**USO PHP Y SQLSERVER**

Comment: Si la pregunta apunta a ejecutar la sentencia EN PHP, falta el código donde intentas hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta es mas bien únicamente de SQL

Pero bastaría con

```html
select * from usuario where id <> "aqui el valor que no quieres"
```